# Result of NULL != value in an SQL query (postgres and rails3)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, null

I ran into a unexpected postgres query issue within my Rails3 app.

I thought I'd run this by stackoverflow and see what the brains of the internet have to say :)

Is this result Expected behaviour (and why?!) or is this a bug?

Given that I have a table, Orders, in my Postgres 9.1.4 database:

```
id        state
=====     ======
1                     <-- nil (default value)
2         'success'
3         'failure'
```

When I run the query:

```
Order.where('orders.state != ?', 'success').map { |order| order.id }
Order Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE (orders.state != 'success')

=> [3]
```

I was expecting the result [1, 3].  There are clearly 2 rows in which (!= 'success') is satisfied.

Why is it that nil != 'success' is not true here?  Does != just ignore NULL values? should it?

NOTE:  I produced the desired result by using the following query:

```
Order.where('orders.state IS NULL OR orders.state != ?', 'success').map { |order| order.id }
Order Load (2.3ms) SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE (orders.state IS NULL OR orders.state != 'success')

=> [1, 3]
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know why but your first request is checking *qb_sync_status* whereas it should check *state*...

Comment: aah, 'cause I poorly copied&pasted this example.  corrected, thanks Sparda

Comment: This is the way the underlying SQL is design to work. The NULL value can cause problems when selecting data because when comparing an unknown value, i.e. NULL, to any other value, the result is always unknown and not included in the final results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an [IS DISTINCT FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html) comparison operator in PostgreSQL:

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, `7 = NULL` yields null, as does `7 <> NULL`. When this behavior is not suitable, use the `IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM` constructs:
>
> ```
> expression IS DISTINCT FROM expression
> expression IS NOT DISTINCT FROM expression
> ```
>
> For non-null inputs, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is the same as the `<>` operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is identical to `=` for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null. Thus, these constructs effectively act as though null were a normal data value, rather than "unknown".

For example, given your sample data:

```
=> select * from orders where state is distinct from 'success';
 id |  state  
----+---------
  1 | 
  3 | failure
(2 rows)
```

So you could say this:

```
Order.where('orders.state is distinct from ?', 'success').pluck(:id)
```

Note that I also switched to `pluck` rather than your `map(&:id)`, that will send this SQL to the database:

```
select id from orders where orders.state is distinct from 'success'
```

rather than `select orders.* ...` with client-side filter to extract the `id`s.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the SQL standard, where a comparison between two values involving at least one NULL returns neither true, nor false, but unknown.

From http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~wlam/compsci/sqlnulls

> - A boolean comparison between two values involving a NULL returns neither true nor false, but unknown in SQL's three-valued logic. [3] For example, neither NULL equals NULL nor NULL not-equals NULL is true. Testing whether a value is NULL requires an expression such as IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.
> - An SQL query selects only values whose WHERE expression evaluates to true, and groups whose HAVING clause evaluates to true.

One solution is to use COALESCE:

```
Order.where('COALESCE(orders.state,"NIL") != ?', 'success').map(&:id)
```

If `orders.state` is NULL, it will replace it with 'NIL', which will then return true or false from the comparison.

You can of course use an additional condition:

```
Order.where('orders.state is null OR orders.state != ?', 'success').map(&:id)
```

Comment: `isnull()` is, AFAIK, a MySQLism. The standard way is to say `orders.state is null`.